# no return from SPARQL DBPedia Company Information

Tags: dbpedia

I fail to recover some fields visible on some page of dbpedia.

I get some fields, but not all. I get for example  `rdf:type`  with

```
select * where {
  values ?comp{ <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Digital_distribution>}.
  ?comp rdf:type ?type
}
```

But

```
select * where {
  values ?comp{ <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Digital_distribution>}.
  ?comp dbo:industry ?indus
}
```

return nothing.

Same problem with some fields in `Apple_Inc`.

Answer (score 1):

Your query (reformatted for clarity) --

```
SELECT * 
WHERE
  { VALUES ?comp 
         { http://dbpedia.org/resource/Digital_distribution } . 
    ?comp  dbo:industry  ?indus 
  }
```

says "get the industries for company `Digital_distribution`".  You want to "get the companies with industry `Digital_distribution`"

Try [this](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20*%20%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fcompany%20%20dbo%3Aindustry%20%20%3Findustry%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%28%20%3Findustry%20%29%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%28%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FDigital_distribution%3E%20%29%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) (see [results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20*%20%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fcompany%20%20dbo%3Aindustry%20%20%3Findustry%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%28%20%3Findustry%20%29%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%28%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FDigital_distribution%3E%20%29%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20))--

```
SELECT * 
WHERE
  { ?company  dbo:industry  ?industry 
    VALUES ( ?industry ) 
         { ( <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Digital_distribution> ) 
         } . 
  }
```